# How to resolve "Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect" Exception?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am very new to hibernate so I am practicing by seeing video tutorial. The link I am following is,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFMOZY4z6bE&list=PL4AFF701184976B25&index=5

It is simple java project in eclipse. Here I use mysql Data base. Here is my Hibernate.cfg.xml file,

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb
        root
        root

```
    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="com.***.dto.UserDetails"/>
```

I am getting this kind of error ,

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found:   org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect
at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.constructDialect(DialectFactory.java:159)
at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:99)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:117)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
at com.aurodisplay.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.constructDialect(DialectFactory.java:156)
```

Can any one help me in this.

Comment: Add jar file containing `org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect`...

Comment: Which hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Hibernate needs a driver in order to be able to connect to MySQL. As Hibernate cannot contain the drivers for every databases, you need to give it yourself.

Comment: its there .. I followed the above video tutorial

Comment: @Jens its 3.6.4 same as in video tutorial

Comment: `MYSQLDialect` is in `hibernate-core`. Check your classpath.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle You mean mysql driver right, I have given mysql-connector-java-5.1.7.jar file

Comment: @Raghu And you run it from eclipse?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup yes in my classpath its in hibernate3.jar file under package `com.hibernate.dialect`

Comment: @Jens yes from eclipse.

Comment: @Raghu and your run configuration uses the buildpath of your project?

Comment: @Jens Sorry I didnt get you.

Comment: @Raghu if you call "run" you run the project with a configuration that can be different from the buildpath. Look if the jar is in "eun Configurations.." --> "your launcher" -->"Classpath"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the question. You've found `MySQLDialect` in your jar files, but your configuration file tries to use `MYSQLDialect`. Java is case-sensitive.

Try changing to below

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a property file, then make sure there is no space at the end of the line.

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
<org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
```

simply remove `8` from there

```
<org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at ...
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 106 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:150)
    ... 116 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I resolved it buy simply removing 5 from org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect, and it worked like a charm.

Here is the code block :

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"
```

Solution : Remove only '5' from MySQL5Dialect.