# Deployment on Wildfly: ClassNotFoundException: Oracle12cDialect

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, wildfly, oracle12c

I am having a problem. I am trying to deploy an application on a WildFly server. While trying to do that, I get an error like this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

I have searched for a solution, I found one - I should add `hibernate-core` jar to `/wildfly/standalone/deployments`... but it doesn't help! Wildfly is trying (without any effort of course) to deploy `hibernate-core`, but that is it, it fails. Then I'm trying to deploy my app - and the same error comes up :/

Maybe I am doing something wrong? Or the problem lies somewhere else?

Cheers and thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: Heve you already seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481330/how-to-resolve-dialect-class-not-found-org-hibernate-dialect-mysqldialect-exc Maybe there is something useful for you

Comment: Also, can you tell us which version of Wildfly you are using?

Comment: @Lorelorelore i am using Wildfly 8.1.0.Final

Answer (score 2):

`Oracle12cDialect` was introduced in Hibernate 5.0 (see [HHH-9044](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/hhh-9044)). Most likely you are using an older Hibernate version which doesn't have `Oracle12cDialect` class.